# Enabling remote login without password authentication

Tags: ssh, remote-control

I have enabled remote login (ssh) on my Mac via System Preferences. But it doesn't work with keys and only works with normal user/pass authentication. I want to disable this behaviour and only allow public key (RSA or DSA) authentication.

I edited `/etc/sshd_config` and uncommented following lines:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
```

I then restarted the Remote Login service but it didn't help. It still allows password authentication and my keys are rejected.

Could anyone help me set this up?

Comment: Please split of the second part (local network only) into a separate question, makes it easier for people to answer just one of them.

Comment: Done - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34091/how-to-enable-remote-login-ssh-only-from-local-networks

Comment: Where and how do you define your authorized keys? Key bases login works fine out of the box.

Comment: @Gerry I have had my personal private/public keys generated for a while now. I used `cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, but no success.

Comment: Did you fiddle with any other sshd settings before? A print out of your sshd_config file could be useful. If not, my guess is your public key is invalid, or does not match your private key, maybe you should try to generate a new key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Allow me to answer myself as I found a resolution.

If `PasswordAuthentication no` doesn't work on its own (and I read in some situations it may) make sure to uncomment and set to "no" this:

```
UsePAM no
```

Kudos for this resolution go to Mac OS X Hints - http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050815135941513&lsrc=osxh.

Comment: On OS X El Capitan 10.11.2 the file to edit is ``/private/etc/ssh/sshd_config``

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion) you also need to comment out the following line in /etc/sshd_config:

```
# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys
```