# How to restrict "Remote Login" (ssh) access to only certain IP ranges?

Tags: ssh, firewall

Can someone please tell me how to restrict SSH access only to certain IP ranges (e.g. local network) and not the whole Internet? I guess this has to be done via firewall.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From `man sshd`:

```
/etc/hosts.allow
/etc/hosts.deny
Access controls that should be enforced by tcp-wrappers are defined here.  
Further details are described in hosts_access(5).
```

https://debian-administration.org/article/87/Keeping_SSH_access_secure offers these examples:

```
# /etc/hosts.allow
sshd: 1.2.3.0/255.255.255.0
sshd: 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0

# /etc/hosts.deny
sshd: ALL
```

The TCP wrapper program in Mac OS X is: `tcpd`

Comment: Does this work on MacOS? My `man sshd` says nothing about `/etc/hosts.allow`.

Comment: This answer is 8 years old. It worked at the time. I don't know what the current solution is, unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I eventually realized that between OpenBSD 5.5 ([man.openbsd.org](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-5.5/hosts_access.5)) and 5.6 it must have been removed.

Answer (score 3):

I did not test this, but I'd try this in terminal:

```
sudo ipfw add allow src-ip 10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/16,192.168.0.0/16 dst-ip me dst-port 22
sudo ipfw add reject src-ip any dst-ip me dst-port 22
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are behind a router and didn't map the port to your computer, that effectively disables SSH access from the internet.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. Unfortunately this isn't really a solution for me as this is for my MacBook Pro which occasionally is connected to networks with external IP and no router in-between.

Comment: That seems very unlikely, and assuming you only have one network adapter, that would imply there is no 'local' network if a public IP address is bound to it.

Comment: Unlikely or not, doesn't really matter, does it? Apart from external IP situation, consider Public WiFi networks. I know which networks are safe for me and I'd like to restrict access to only these networks. My question is a little more generic though which was my intention.

Comment: I'd suggest rephrasing the question then. Sounds like you are looking to whitelist (some) IP ranges for some services in the firewall.

Comment: Done as suggested. Cheers.