# How do I allow a single IP to access everything on my Mac?

Tags: macos, security, network, firewall

I tried [IceFloor](http://www.hanynet.com/icefloor/), but it's not working to white list all traffic from a single IP to bypass firewalls.

Comment: In a specific way or just access? SSH? Remote?

Comment: Initially it's a local IP accessing a webserver.

Answer (score 1):

> The firewall in Mac OS X v10.5.1 and later is an Application Firewall,
>   which allows you to control connections on a per-application basis,
>   rather than a per-port basis. This makes it easier to gain the
>   benefits of firewall protection, and helps prevent undesirable
>   applications from taking control of network ports that have been
>   opened for legitimate applications.

You can not limit or allow access via ip address using the OS X firewall.  You can use ssh and set restrictions in /etc/sshd_config.  For limiting to certain ip addresses only [see this answer.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/40779/4153)