# Configuring OS X Firewall to enable SSH/SCP only on the local subnet?

Tags: ssh, firewall

We would like to configure OS X to only allow Remote File Sharing (SCP) from a specific range of internal IP addresses. That way they only accessible when the user is connected via the VPN.

What's the preferred method? Doesn't seem to be doable via the Security & Privacy tab.

Comment: did you have a look at the littlesnitch app

Comment: Just found this - didn't show up in my searches earlier - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34091/how-to-restrict-remote-login-ssh-access-to-only-certain-ip-ranges?rq=1

Comment: Great, I gave you points for that, but will also close your question as duplicate for house keeping reasons.

Answer (score 0):

IceFloor is a frontend/GUI for the system firewall pf and should be able to be configured to do just what you want.
http://www.hanynet.com/icefloor/