# How to use SSH keys and disable password authentication

Tags: macos, ssh

I'm trying to access a Mac remotely (I do have physical access to this Mac) through SSH from a Linux client computer. My goal is to access this Mac from outside the network. Port forwarding is set up on the router. From my client computer I'm able to `ssh user@ip` for the public IP and I am able to get into the Mac, so port forwarding is working.

Now I want to set up SSH keys. I've generated SSH keys on my client computer but I wanted to get the SSH Daemon on the Mac setup first. I edited `/etc/ssh_config` and set `PasswordAuthentication no`. I restarted SSH with these commands: `sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`, then `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`. When I try to SSH in from the client again, it still asks for my password.

I took a look at [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34090/enabling-remote-login-without-password-authentication) and from the answer I added `UsePAM no` to the config file and restarted the service with `launchctl` again. I'm still being prompted for a password.

I also tried the solution [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84523/disable-password-authentication-on-ssh-server-on-os-x-server-10-8). I'm still being prompted for a password.

How do I set up my `ssh_config` to so that it doesn't ask for the password and only accepts SSH keys? Am I not restarting the daemon properly? Is there another step I am missing?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I was editing the wrong configuration file! Instead of `/etc/ssh_config`, I edited `private/etc/sshd_config`. I think this probably would have also worked if I edited `/etc/sshd_config` as per the updated answer from @GhostLyrics, but I didn't test that yet so I can't say for sure. After that, I restarted the service with `sudo launchctl stop com.openssh.sshd` and then `sudo launchctl start com.openssh.sshd` and I was able to get my desired behavior. Here is the resource where I found the pertinent information: https://superuser.com/questions/364304/how-do-i-configure-ssh-on-os-x

Here are the config options I changed:

```
PermitRootLogin no
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

After that I was successfully able to generate SSH keys on my client computer, moved the public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the Mac and set permissions for that file to 644.

It is important to note that those permissions are for my **public key**. My **private key** permissions are set to 600 on my client computer. This is *really* important if you have both your public and private key in your `~/.ssh` folder and there are multiple users on the system. If your **private key** permissions are set to 644 then *any* user could read your private key and impersonate you. Also, the permissions for the `~/.ssh` folder should be 700.

Comment: Internally, `/etc/sshd_config` and `/private/etc/sshd_config` are the same file. :)

Answer (score 16):

I'm using Apple-M1 (11.3) now and I found that only setting `PasswordAuthentication no` does not work, but these two options are enough:

```bsh
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 11):

`/etc/ssh/ssh_config` is the configuration file for the client which is used if you don't have a more specific one in your home directory. What you want to edit is `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` which is the one for the server.

You will probably want to set `PermitRootLogin without-password` (or `no`) and `PasswordAuthentication no` there.

---

Update:
Since you are running Yosemite, the file is `/etc/sshd_config` according to this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/167405/11135

To further elaborate why it still prompts when setting `PasswordAuthentication no` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` it is important to understand what you configured. "When making an *outgoing* connection via SSH, don't offer password authentication."

Comment: I don't have a `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, only a `/etc/ssh_config`. I'm running on Yosemite. I did try the `PasswordAuthentication no` but it's still prompting me for the password.

Comment: Ah, I see. That is not what I want. I want to SSH from my Linux client to the Mac with keys and without a password. What should I change for an _incoming_ connection?

Comment: `/etc/sshd_config` → `PasswordAuthentication no`. Sorry for the confusion. Please let me know how I can make the answer more clear. :)

Comment: I'm still getting the same behavior. It prompts me for a password when I ssh from the Linux machine to the Mac.

Comment: Let's continue this in chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/34931/discussion-on-pubkey-only-ssh?tab=general

Comment: Sorry to annoy you again, but when re-reading the chatlog, I found that you pasted the *client* file again, instead of the server configuration! http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27140965#27140965