# Change `sshd_config` on Big Sur to alter port and disallow password authentication

Tags: ssh

I’ve searched the web, I really have. Yet I can’t find a single answer to this basic question: how do I change the sshd config on MacOS Big Sur?

I’ve changed the configuration at `/private/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, modifying the port and disallowing `PasswordAuthentication`.

I’ve restarted `com.openssh.ssh-agent`.

This has had no effect.

Comment: Does the answer from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225231/how-to-use-ssh-keys-and-disable-password-authentication?rq=1 not help? Can you add the relevant part of the config file to the question?

Comment: @nohillside I have tried that and can confirm that it does not work on Big Sur. I know for a fact that the config changes aren’t taking effect because I’m changing the port. Regardless of password authentication, I just shouldn’t get a connection on `:22`. Yet I still do.

Comment: Can you try one step at a time? Just switch from password to public key and try whether this works? Also, how do you restart `com.openssh.ssh-agent`?

Comment: What would restarting the agent have to do with the port the server is running on?

Comment: @MarcWilson Typically when changing a configuration one restarts the associated service so it picks up the change.

Comment: @nohillside Didn't work by just doing one at a time. Restarted all the ways I can think of: `launchctl`, unchecking/rechecking the box in Sharing, rebooting. Nada.

Comment: Strange. Disabling passwords works for me here on Big Sur. Wonder what you do different.

Comment: You need to restart `com.openssh.sshd`